# How to get the next tree elements of a list

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

**This question is more about best practice than about fetching elements from a list.**

I have an ArrayList which I am itaration though by using a simple for-loop. In case a certain keyword shows up, I need to compare the next tree elements to a certain pattern.

```
private static boolean areVectorArgumentsValid(ArrayList<String> fileContent)
{
    for (int i=0; i<fileContent.size(); i++)
    {
        if (fileContent.get(i).equals(NORMAL) || fileContent.get(i).equals(VERTEX))
        {
            // get the next three elements of "fileContent" and see if they match a certain pattern
        }
    }
return true;
}
```

My first approach would be to use another for-loop within the actual outler loop and then increment i by 3:

```
for (int j=i+1; j<=i+3; j++)
{
    if (!fileContent.get(j).matches(PATTERN))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
i+=3;
```

As you see, it is not hard to make the method do what I want it to do, but... I am not sure if there might be a way which you'd call *more elegant*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This question is more about best practice than about fetching elements
>   from a list.

Before going into details few remarks..

- `NORMAL.equals(fileContent.get(i))` instead of  `fileContent.get(i).equals(NORMAL)` will avoid `NullPointerException`
- Before iterating for next three element you should first check whether your `List` has next three element or not to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

---

Now If it's about checking for only next three elements and only return false if any of the three element does not match the pattern than you can have something like following,

```
   if (fileContent.size() < i + 3 
    && (!fileContent.get(i+1).matches(PATTERN)
        || !fileContent.get(i+2).matches(PATTERN) 
        || !fileContent.get(i+3).matches(PATTERN))) {
        return false;
   }
```

***Problem*** in this approach is it will not check if your list does not have next three elements.

As for your approach by allowing check of next available elements you can just add one condition to check whether your list has next element or not in ***loop*** before calling `get` method on the list.Your approach to iterate over next three element seems fine but following improvement is needed.

```
for (int j=i+1; j<=i+3; j++){
    if (fileContent.size() < j && !fileContent.get(j).matches(PATTERN)){
        return false;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of adding check for next three elements, the for loop could only be till n-3 where n is the length of the list

Comment: Thanks for you input. Bot now that there are plenty of answers on how to deal with this problem I am a little confused. :)
The easiest way would probably be to just stick with the inner for-loop but using streams and lambdas and/or an Iterator looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat three times and use `++i` when getting the element:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if (!fileContent.get(++i).matches(PATTERN)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or do something like this with stream:

```
if (fileContent.stream().skip(i).limit(3).anyMatch(s -> !s.matches(PATTERN))) {
    return false;
}
i += 3;
```

But I think the best solution would be completely changing it and using an `Iterator`:

```
private static boolean areVectorArgumentsValid(ArrayList<String> fileContent) {
    for (Iterator<String> it = fileContent.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String s = it.next();
        if (!s.equals(NORMAL) && !s.equals(VERTEX)) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (!it.hasNext() || !it.next().matches(PATTERN)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is it actially better to use Iterators in general? Any how to Iterators behave performace-wise?

Comment: @Vulpecula Depends on the type of the list. For example, when using `LinkedList` you should always use `Iterator` when iterating, but for `ArrayList` there's no big difference performance-wise. So in this case you can use the one that you consider more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should make a method, that takes the array and index to start looking from, and return boolean if it match the three or not. It is the elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just one loop by introducing a state :

```
private static boolean areVectorArgumentsValid(ArrayList<String> fileContent)
{
    int state = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<fileContent.size(); i++)
    {
         switch (state) {
         case 0:
             if (fileContent.get(i).equals(NORMAL) || fileContent.get(i).equals(VERTEX))
                 state++;
             break;
         case 1:
         case 2:
         case 3:
             if (!fileContent.get(i).matches(PATTERN))
                 return false;
             state = (state + 1) % 4;
             break;
    }
    return true;
}
```